# Styling of biblography - change underline to italic (Latex)

Tags: latex, bibliography

I am struggeling with latex biblography styling.

Using the predefined

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

style i get a nice result:

[image]

When adding the following package:

```
\usepackage {ulem}
```

I get this result in the biblography:

[image]

How can i remove the underline of the journal and get it italic?

I tried:

```
\renewcommand{\uline}[1]{\textit{#1}}
```

and also following, to undefine \uline

```
\renewcommand\uline[1]{}
```

But both create a lot of "Missing } inserted.\end{thebibliography}" in the bbl file. Is there a way to revert the \usepackage command or get back the old style?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the features of the `ulem` package is to redefine `\emph` so that it uses `\uline`, so (as is presumably already clear to you) that's why you're getting underline in the bibliography, where text was emphasised before.

The documentation for the `ulem` package notes that adding the `[normalem]` option when loading the `ulem` package means that `\uline` is defined but `\emph` isn't redefined.  I don't know if that would be an acceptable solution for you – ie, do you in fact want `\emph` to be underlined throughout the rest of the document?

Alternatively, if you only want `\emph` to go back to its original definition for the bibliography, you could *try* (`ulem` docs again) giving the command `\normalem` before loading the bibliography.  However, the way that the bibliography is loaded can sometimes make it unexpectedly difficult to fiddle with its formatting (as you've discovered, when trying to redefine `\uline`).

If these thoughts don't resolve things, try posting a ‘[minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)’.  You may also be better off looking at, or possibly posting to, the [TeX stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: \normalem worked for me. Thanks for the answer, solution and explanation

Answer (score 1):

If anyone faced the issue of getting `\hbuf` errors in the Bibliography.
The Solution by NormanGrey helps in this case also:

> The documentation for the ulem package notes that adding the [normalem] option when loading the ulem package...

Thus, just by making a small change in the `settings.tex` fixed this error:

> \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

It not only removed the underline, it fixed the overflow I had, as you can see here:

[image]

to

[image]

Thank you a lot.